# Cross formatter java/html for eclipse and intellij

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, formatter

In the company I works for by default the IDE is Eclipse, but we have some new products using android. Because of Android Studio some developers are using IntelliJ, so I'm looking for an effective way to keep the same code formatting between Eclipse and Android Studio / IntelliJ.

For the java code the problem has already been solved, the two options below work perfectly:

- https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6546-eclipse-code-formatter
- https://github.com/google/styleguide

The problem is to keep the same formatting between the HTML / XML files.

NOtes:

- Export eclipse settings: only displays "Java Code Style Preferences", there is no "HTML Code Style Preferences".
- eclipse code formatter plugin for intelliJ: only supports Java, Javacripr, C / C ++ and GWT
- Using Google style Guide for Java (intelliJ): the HTML formatter inherits the formatting applied in Java
- Using Google style guide for Java (Eclipse): the HTML formatter does NOT inherit the formatting applied in Java

Notes 2:

- I also tested http://editorconfig.org/ but it does not meet all the needs

What tool / configuration can I use to keep the same formatting in HTML / XML files in the Eclipse / Android Studio / IntelliJ IDE?

Comment: Why would an HTML formatted inherit Java formatting? What would it inherit?

Comment: https://github.com/google/styleguide/blob/gh-pages/intellij-java-google-style.xml check line 105

Comment: Thanks for making it clear that https://github.com/google/styleguide has same java code style with multiple editors -- eclipse and intelliJ